# Fixed vs floating point representation doubts

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision, fixed-point

I have an exam tomorrow for which I need to know about both fixed and floating point representations. I think I've understood the basic idea behind both, but when it comes to comparing their features I'm not quite sure about the details. I'll note down what I feel is correct from the understanding that I have about both, and would greatly appreciate it if someone could confirm whether it's correct or point out what's wrong.

Fixed point -

a. Faster than floating point implementation

b. Can represent any value accurately within its range

c. Allows simple multiplication by 2

Floating point -

a. Provides best resolution (I'm assuming resolution means precision)

b. Copes with a wide range of numbers

c. Can't represent some values with exact accuracy in its range

d. Implementation is slightly more complicated

Thank you.

Comment: Re: "[Fixed point] Can represent any value accurately within its range": Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by that, but I don't think it's true. For example, 1/3 can't be represented exactly by any fixed-point system I've ever encountered.

Comment: Most of the above are either completely wrong or too vague.

Comment: ruakh - Now that I think about it, I agree that 1/3 would have a more accurate floating point representation. Does this mean that floating point has better accuracy AND precision as compared to fixed point? 



PaulR - Sorry about that. This was one of the questions in an assignment which I struggled to answer because the concepts weren't explained very clearly. I'm just basing all this off stuff I've read on Wikipedia/other parts of the net.

Comment: I've put together some comments in an answer below now.

Comment: @ruakh: Pixel intensities are commonly represented on a fixed scale from 0 (0) to 255 (1). On this scale, 85 represents exactly 1/3.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Interesting. I don't see it that way -- in my experience they're actually represented on a fixed scale from 0 (0) to 255 (255) -- but it's an interesting perspective. Regardless, even under your interpretation of pixel values, where 255 represents 1, that's not "fixed point", since a fixed-point representation of 1 will necessarily be an integer power of the radix.

Comment: @NobleSixTaniguchi The accuracy when representing 1/3 depends on the number of bits used to represent the mantissa (in floating point) or the fractional part of a fixed-point number. It's possible for fixed-point to give a more accurate representation of 1/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed point -

a. Faster than floating point implementation
   - TRUE/FALSE - can be faster or slower depending on hardware

b. Can represent any value accurately within its range
   - FALSE

c. Allows simple multiplication by 2
   - "simple" compared to what ? For floating point you add 1 to the exponent, for fixed point you either do an integer multiply or a shift left. I don't see any significant difference in complexity.

Floating point -

a. Provides best resolution (I'm assuming resolution means precision)
   - partially TRUE - but "best" compared to what ? Do you just mean better than fixed point ?

b. Copes with a wide range of numbers
   - TRUE

c. Can't represent some values with exact accuracy in its range
   - TRUE - but can't represent *the vast majority* of values with exact accuracy

d. Implementation is slightly more complicated
   - TRUE - but again, "slightly more complicated" than what ? Floating point requires a lot more logic (i.e transistors/gates/silicon) than fixed point, if that's what you mean ?

Comment: Allows simple multiplication by 2 : I wasn't quite sure what was meant by that, but I guess the question regards a shift left operation to be more complicated. 

Provides best resolution : Yeah, I meant better than fixed point for that. 

Implementation is slightly more complicated : I think requiring more logic is what the question was looking for, yes.

Thank you for your help, that explanation was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Re: "For floating point you add 1 to the exponent" to multiply by two: That only works for normalized numbers. In particular, it does *not* work for zero. (I think the OP was quite right to say that multiplication by two is simpler with fixed-point than with floating-point, since floating-point has more edge-cases, *and* these edge-cases are more complex.)

Comment: @ruakh: fair point, but note that for both fixed point and floating point you need to check for edge cases if you're going to make a fair comparison. I agree though that the floating point implementation with be slightly more complicated, but that's generally true for most operations compared to integer/fixed point.